# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Expiry

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone explain to me how ASP.NET Forms Authentication works because I don't seem to get it and I keep getting signed out.

As it stands, I have username, password and a "Keep me signed in" checkbox. From these values I'm creating a ticket and cookie, as follows:

```
    // Create ticket
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,email,DateTime.UtcNow,DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),remember,String.Empty);

    // Encrypt ticket
    string cookie_contents = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Create cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,cookie_contents);

    if (remember) {
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(90);
    }

    cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
    cookie.Secure = true;

    // Add cookie to response
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I would expect with this code that I can sign in to my website and assuming I check "Keep me signed in" that I stay signed in, for at least 90 days?

However what I am seeing is that I'm being signed out at least 30 minutes after initial login (which is the time set aside for the ticket?).

What is the difference between cookie expiration and ticket expiration and how do I keep myself signed. Do I need to set 90 days to both cookie and ticket?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't manipulate the cookie directly if you can avoid it. You can use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, persistent)` to sign a user in. Persistent here means "don't use session cookie".

You should then specify the cookie expiry in web.config under

```
 <system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
             <forms timeout="50000000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
   </authentication>
 </system.web>
```

where sliding expiration means that the cookie will be renewed for each request. Timeout is in minutes, so the example is pretty high :)

Take a look at this question and the link to Scott Gu's blog: [Forms Authentication Cookie Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059261/forms-authentication-cookie-expiration/13358214#13358214)

Comment: What about cookie.Secure with SSL? I've added requireSSL to the forms tag as well. Also slidingExpiration renews on activity, but what about no activity? i.e I'll close the browser and come back later...

Comment: yes requireSSL="true" in that tag above will make it a secure cookie. Another good tag to use is enableCrossAppRedirects="false"

Comment: OK I think I got it, set timeout to something crazy like 30 days and sliding expiration should take care of the rest + it expires if they don't sign in within that timeframe.

Comment: Scott Gu's blog link that is provided is the best way to do it

Comment: If *don't use session cookie*, what use ?

Comment: **Maximun value**: `timeout="50000000"` ?

Comment: Cookies has either "session" scope, approximately meaning "until browser is closed". Max value is probably int.MaxValue. Which is a little more than 4000 years :)

Comment: Max value for timeout=525600 (=1 year)

Comment: @spiros I guess this is a new limit then. I ran a website with 2 years expiry time until a few weeks ago. But anything above 3 months is mostly an academic expiration today, given browser policies etc.